# mpi4py compilation error on a Suse system

Tags: python, openmpi, mpi4py

After I compile the mpi4py with the openmpi from the server I get a runtime error.

```
 OS: SuSe
 GCC: 4.8.5
 OpenMPI: 1.10.1
 HDF5: 1.8.11
 mpi4py: 2.0.0
 Python: 2.7.9
```

**Environment Settings:**
I use virtualenv (no admin permission of the server)

```
(ENV) username@servername:~/test> echo $PATH
/opt/local/tools/hdf5/hdf5-1.8.11_openmpi-1.10.1_gcc-4.8.5/bin:/opt/local/mpi/openmpi/openmpi-1.10.1_gcc-4.8.5/bin:/home/username/test/virtualenv-15.0.3/ENV/bin: [other libs ] :/opt/local/bin:/usr/lib64/mpi/gcc/openmpi/bin:/usr/local/bin:/usr/bin:/bin

(ENV) username@servername:echo $LD_LIBRARY_PATH 
/opt/local/tools/hdf5/hdf5-1.8.11_openmpi-1.10.1_gcc-4.8.5/lib:/opt/local/mpi/openmpi/openmpi-1.10.1_gcc-4.8.5/lib


(ENV) username@servername:~/test> pip freeze
cycler==0.10.0
Cython==0.24.1
dill==0.2.5
matplotlib==1.5.3
multiprocessing==2.6.2.1
numpy==1.11.1
pyfits==3.4
pyparsing==2.1.9
python-dateutil==2.5.3
pytz==2016.6.1
scipy==0.18.1
six==1.10.0
```

Compile and install mpi4py:

```
(ENV) username@servername:~/test> wget https://bitbucket.org/mpi4py/mpi4py/downloads/mpi4py-2.0.0.tar.gz
(ENV) username@servername:~/test> tar xzvf mpi4py-2.0.0.tar.gz
(ENV) username@servername:~/test> cd mpi4py-2.0.0/
(ENV) username@servername:~/test>vim mpi.cfg
```

In mpi.cfg I added a section for my custom Open MPI:

```
[mpi]
mpi_dir              = /opt/local/mpi/openmpi/openmpi-1.10.1_gcc-4.8.5
mpicc                = %(mpi_dir)s/bin/mpicc
mpicxx               = %(mpi_dir)s/bin/mpicxx
library_dirs         = %(mpi_dir)s/lib
runtime_library_dirs = %(library_dirs)s
```

Compile

```
(ENV) username@servername:python setup.py build --mpi=mpi
```

Install

```
(ENV) username@servername:python setup.py install
```

First basic test (ok)

```
(ENV) username@servername: mpiexec -n 5 python -m mpi4py helloworld
Hello, World! I am process 0 of 5 on servername.
Hello, World! I am process 1 of 5 on servername.
Hello, World! I am process 2 of 5 on servername.
Hello, World! I am process 3 of 5 on servername.
Hello, World! I am process 4 of 5 on servername.
```

Second basic test generates ERROR:

```
(ENV) username@servername: python
>>>from mpi4py import MPI
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
Error obtaining unique transport key from ORTE orte_precondition_transports not present in the environment).

Local host: servername
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
--------------------------------------------------------------------------
It looks like MPI_INIT failed for some reason; your parallel process is likely to abort.  There are many reasons that a parallel process can fail during MPI_INIT; some of which are due to configuration or environment problems.  This failure appears to be an internal failure; here's some additional information (which may only be relevant to an Open MPI developer):

PML add procs failed
--> Returned "Error" (-1) instead of "Success" (0)
-------------------------------------------------------------------------    
*** An error occurred in MPI_Init_thread
*** on a NULL communicator
*** MPI_ERRORS_ARE_FATAL (processes in this communicator will now abort,
***    and potentially your MPI job)
[servername:165332] Local abort before MPI_INIT completed successfully; not able to aggregate error messages, and not able to guarantee that all other processes were killed!
(ENV) username@servername:~/test/mpi4py-2.0.0>
```

Update: during the compilation of mpi4py I get this error

```
checking for library 'lmpe' ...
/opt/local/mpi/openmpi/openmpi-1.10.1_gcc-4.8.5/bin/mpicc -pthread 
-fno-strict-aliasing -fmessage-length=0 -grecord-gcc-switches -fstack-
protector -O2 -Wall -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -funwind-tables -fasynchronous-
unwind-tables -g -DNDEBUG -fmessage-length=0 -grecord-gcc-switches 
-fstack-protector -O2 -Wall -D_FORTIFY_SOURCE=2 -funwind-tables 
-fasynchronous-unwind tables -g -DOPENSSL_LOAD_CONF -fPIC -I/opt/local
/mpi/openmpi/openmpi-1.10.1_gcc-4.8.5/include -c _configtest.c -o 
_configtest.o
/opt/local/mpi/openmpi/openmpi-1.10.1_gcc-4.8.5/bin/mpicc -pthread _configtest.o -L/opt/local/mpi/openmpi/openmpi-1.10.1_gcc-4.8.5/lib -Wl,-R/opt/local/mpi/openmpi/openmpi-1.10.1_gcc-4.8.5/lib -llmpe -o _configtest
/usr/lib64/gcc/x86_64-suse-linux/4.8/../../../../x86_64-suse-linux 
bin/ld:   cannot find -llmpe
collect2: error: ld returned 1 exit status
failure.
```

Comment: Update see: https://bitbucket.org/mpi4py/mpi4py/issues/52/mpi4py-compilation-error

Answer (score 0, accepted):

See: https://bitbucket.org/mpi4py/mpi4py/issues/52/mpi4py-compilation-error

It seems the issue was not because of an mpi4py bug but from the  psm transport layer from the OpenMPI

In my case setting

```
export OMPI_MCA_mtl=^psm
```

solved the above runtime error.